# count consecutive rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the ids here with the consecutive 1 occurring 3 or more time. So in the output i shall only see 5,6,7,8. Can someone help me with the query here ??

```
+------+----------+
| id   | diff_chk |
+------+----------+
|    2 |        1 |
|    3 |        2 |
|    5 |        1 |
|    6 |        1 |
|    7 |        1 |
|    8 |        1 |
|    9 |        3 |
|   12 |        1 |
|   13 |        1 |
+------+----------
```

Expected output;

```
id
5
6
7
8
```

The query I tried using is not fetching me the correct results I used the below logic.

```
 select id,COUNT(1) OVER( PARTITION BY diff_chk ORDER BY id ) as w_func from table1 where w_func!=1
```

Comment: can you create it as a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) and include the link here.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Id columns with values 5,6,7,8 as mentioned in my post

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [gaps and islands](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9130/sql-server-window-functions-gaps-and-islands-problem/) problem. Try the following and here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6gY2njDmEtDZPzTbAYRtwT/1) in `MySql 8.0`.

```
select
    id
from
(   
  select
        diff_chck,
        id,
        count(*) over (partition by diff_chck, rnk) as total
    from
    (
        select
            diff_chck,
            id,
            id - row_number() over (partition by diff_chck order by id) as rnk
        from myTable
    ) t
) vals
where total > 2

order by
    id
```

Output:

```
*-----*
| id  |
*-----*
| 5   |
| 6   |
| 7   |
| 8   |
*-----*
```

Comment: as I mentioned i want the id of the consecutive number that is 5,6,7,8

Comment: @user7422128 try now. updated the answer and also demo link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the MySQL version is 8+ you may use

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT id, 
                 diff_chk,
                 id - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) group_num
          FROM test 
          WHERE diff_chk = 1 ),
cte2 as ( SELECT id, 
                 diff_chk,
                 COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY group_num) group_count
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT id
FROM cte2
WHERE group_count >= 3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2dabcaf4bab8a3c47925415344f1a275)

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE that returns the groups of consecutive `1`s:

```
with cte as (
  select *, sum(diff_chk <> 1) over (order by id) grp
  from tablename    
)  
select id
from cte
where diff_chk = 1
  and grp in (select grp from cte where diff_chk = 1 group by grp having count(*) >= 3)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uMKjiY4ZrWyQaDQGRyj8e9/2).
Results:

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 5   |
| 6   |
| 7   |
| 8   |
```